# Passing custom project properties from Visual Studio Extension during build

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, vsx, vsix

How can I pass a custom MsBuild property to Visual Studio build engine from Visual Studio Extension (I want to write a custom add-in) ? Just like Visual Studio itself is passing properties like `$(Configuration)` and `$(Platform)`, I would like to attach to a build process and pass my own property (e.g. `$(MyCustomProperty) = "foobar"`). I know it can be accomplished using MsBuild command line (`/p:Property`), but I want to do it from an extension.

Here is an example of what I would like to accompilsh: a textbox on visual studio toolbar, where user can type in some text - a value, that I would like to pass to build engine.

Then in .csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <MyCustomProperty Condition=" '$(MyCustomProperty)' == '' ">DefaultValue</MyCustomProperty>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(MyCustomProperty)' = 'DoAfterBuild' ">
  ...
</Target>
```

So target `AfterBuild` would be exectued only if user typed `DoAfterBuild` into my extension's text box

Comment: How Visual Studio Extension invoked MSBUILD?

Comment: @NickCarlson - I do not want to invoke MsBuild, but .csproj files ARE MsBuild scripts and Visual Studio is passing actual values of $(Platform) and $(Configuration) variables during build. I want to have $(MyOwnProperty) value passed to this script, so I can use it (e.g. <Target Name="SomeTarget" Condition="$(MyOwnProperty) == 'foobar'">)

Comment: In your original post you said you want to be able to define your own property via a Visual Studio Extension, but now you're saying that you don't want to invoke MSBUILD.  Are you writing your own extension and want to define your own custom properties?  Perhaps a code sample would help illustrate the problem.

Comment: * A Visual Studio Extension is an add-on program that extends the functionality of Visual Studio.  (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/).  Did you write a Visual Studio Extension and are somehow wanting to pass properties to MSBUILD, or by "Visual Studio Extension" are you referring to a C# project file who's file EXTENSION is associated with Visual Studio?

Comment: @NickCarlson - I meant an add-on for Visual Studio (which is commonly referred to as Visual Studio extension - VSX for short) and I said that I do not want to invoke MSBUILD because Visual Studio is not internally using MSBUILD command line but has an integrated build system (based or related to MSBUILD - it is not important).  I updated the question with an example of what I would like to accomplish.

Comment: did you ever find out? it's a good question.

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa unfortunately not

Comment: @MaciejWozniak: I have been developing vs extensions for the past last 6 months or so, and I just noticed this thread again, now a little smarter :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can request service [`IVsBuildPropertyStorage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsbuildpropertystorage), it has following method:

> SetPropertyValue:  Used by a project subtype to set an MSBuild property value.

Something like this:

```
EnvDTE.Project proj = ...;
var sol = Package.GetGlobalService(typeof(VsSolution)) as IVsSolution;
IVsHierarchy hier;
sol.GetProjectOfUniqueName(p.UniqueName, out hier);
var storage = hier as IVsBuildPropertyStorage;
storage.SetPropertyValue(..);
```